# jQuery JavaScript Nested Asynchronous Functions callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-callback

I'm a little confused how to determine when async function called multiple times from another one is finished a call from the last iteration:

```
function MainAsyncFunction(callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    SubAsyncFunction(function(success) {
      if (i >= 10 && success) { // THIS IS WRONG?!
        callback(true); // happens too early
      }
    });
  }
};

function SubAsyncFunction(callback) {
  SubSubAsyncFunction(function() {
        callback(true);
  });
}
```

What I'm doing is calling the [Google Distance Matrix service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_requests), which has a limitation of 25 destinations, hence I'm having to split my array of destinations to call this service multiple times but I don't understand when it's finished.

and in the main bit of code I can tell that the second iteration of the loop in the *MainAsyncFunction* hasn't yet completed when it does a call back.

I think my problem is I haven't got my head around the order of events when dealing with Async functions in JavaScript... please explain how the subject is normally achieved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the jQuery [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object, which acts as a token representing the status of an async operation.

The following is a simplified example:

```
//set up your sub method so that it returns a Deferred object
function doSomethingAsync() {
    var token = $.Deferred();
    myAsyncMethodThatTakesACallback(function() {
        //resolve the token once the async operation is complete
        token.resolve();
    });
    return token.promise();
};

//then keep a record of the tokens from the main function
function doSomethingAfterAllSubTasks() {
    var tokens = [];
    for (var i=0; i < 100; i++) {
        //store all the returned tokens
        tokens.push(doSomethingAsync());
    }

    $.when.apply($,tokens)
        .then(function() {
            //once ALL the sub operations are completed, this callback will be invoked
            alert("all async calls completed");
        });
};
```

The following is an updated version of the OP's updated code:

```
function MainAsyncFunction(callback) {
  var subFunctionTokens = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    subFunctionTokens.push(SubAsyncFunction());
  }

  $.when.apply($,subFunctionTokens)
  .then(function() {
    callback(true);
  });
};

function SubAsyncFunction() {
  var token = $.Deferred();
  SubSubAsyncFunction(function() {
        token.resolve();
  });
  return token.promise();
};​
```

Comment: hey, I do like the idea but don't fully understand implementation and unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BBjbK/

Comment: @Tsar, thats because I made a mistake in the code - `$.when` doesn't take an array so we need to use `apply` to get it working.  I've updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/stevegreatrex/BBjbK/3/

Comment: now we're talking, thanks a lot, man! I'll have to read up on `Deferred();` but this time it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [ajaxStop() event](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/)? This is a jQuery event that only fires when all active AJAX requests are completed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the value of `i` is constantly changing in the loop, finally being out of bounds after failing the loop conditional.

The easiest way to fix this is:

```
for( i=0; i<5; i++) { // or whatever your loop is
    (function(i) {
        // the value of i is now "anchored" in this block.
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Or use `$.each(data, function(index, item) { ... })`

Comment: If you want to bloat the code by another several hundred commands for no good reason, sure, knock yourself out...

Comment: Assuming you're referring to jQuery, the OP's already using it (he's included the tag) so he gets `each` for free and I personally think its a little more readable.  Point taken though

Comment: What I meant is that calling `each` adds another massive number of commands for JS to execute, whereas mine is as simple as it gets. I don't approve of jQuery in general for this reason. Every site I've seen that uses it lags in all browsers and all computers I test in... Meanwhile I produce similar or better effects in raw JS and have to double-check if it's supposed to go that fast.

Comment: hi the problem is different, it calls back too early - the problem is my criterion for MainFunction callback. I need to know when the very last SubFunction call is processed.

Comment: You could do this by having a counter variable. Increase it by 1 when you start an async call, and decrease it by 1 when said async call completes. If the counter is 0, all async calls have completed.

Comment: @Kolink would that not fail if say one iteration completes earlier than the next one started?

Comment: @Kolink ..or I could work out how many SubAsyncFunction calls there will be, set it to a global var N and then decrease it by 1 every time SubAsyncFunction completes? is this the best solution tho?